# aligning checkboxes with labels

Tags: html, css

I cant align the checkboxes to their labels, they float one line higher and on mobile they are underneath the label.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHJyi.jpg)

The problem happens on all checkboxes, so when you pick the Primary school teacher option and headteacher from the dropdown.

The link to the page is https://careermapforprimary.co.uk/#register

I've tried to add some CSS but it didn't work.

`.mc-field-group input[type="checkbox"] { vertical-align: middle; }`

any suggestions please?

This is the code to create the form fields, there is no css:

```
 <div id="conditional-fields-primary-teacher" style="display: none;">
    <div class="mc-field-group">
       <label for="mce-FNAME">First name <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
       <label for="mce-LNAME">Last name <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
       <label for="mce-JOB_TITLE">Job title <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" value="" name="JOB_TITLE" class="required" id="mce-JOB_TITLE" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
       <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
       <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
       <label for="mce-REGION">Region <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
       <select name="REGION" class="required" id="mce-REGION" required>
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="Bedfordshire">Bedfordshire</option>
          <option value="Berkshire">Berkshire</option>
          <option value="Bristol">Bristol</option>
          <option value="Buckinghamshire">Buckinghamshire</option>
          <option value="Cambridgeshire">Cambridgeshire</option>
          <option value="Cheshire">Cheshire</option>
          <option value="Cornwall">Cornwall</option>
          <option value="Cumbria">Cumbria</option>
          <option value="Derbyshire">Derbyshire</option>
          <option value="Devon">Devon</option>
          <option value="Dorset">Dorset</option>
          <option value="Durham">Durham</option>
          <option value="East Sussex">East Sussex</option>
          <option value="Essex">Essex</option>
          <option value="Gloucestershire">Gloucestershire</option>
          <option value="Greater London">Greater London</option>
          <option value="Greater Manchester">Greater Manchester</option>
          <option value="Hampshire">Hampshire</option>
          <option value="Herefordshire">Herefordshire</option>
          <option value="Isle of Wight">Isle of Wight</option>
          <option value="Kent">Kent</option>
          <option value="Lancashire">Lancashire</option>
          <option value="Leicestershire">Leicestershire</option>
          <option value="Lincolnshire">Lincolnshire</option>
          <option value="Merseyside">Merseyside</option>
          <option value="Norfolk">Norfolk</option>
          <option value="North Yorkshire">North Yorkshire</option>
          <option value="Northamptonshire">Northamptonshire</option>
          <option value="Northumberland">Northumberland</option>
          <option value="Nottinghamshire">Nottinghamshire</option>
          <option value="Oxfordshire">Oxfordshire</option>
          <option value="Rutland">Rutland</option>
          <option value="Shropshire">Shropshire</option>
          <option value="Somerset">Somerset</option>
          <option value="South Yorkshire">South Yorkshire</option>
          <option value="Staffordshire">Staffordshire</option>
          <option value="Suffolk">Suffolk</option>
          <option value="Surrey">Surrey</option>
          <option value="Tyne and Wear">Tyne and Wear</option>
          <option value="Warwickshire">Warwickshire</option>
          <option value="West Midlands">West Midlands</option>
          <option value="West Sussex">West Sussex</option>
          <option value="West Yorkshire">West Yorkshire</option>
          <option value="Wiltshire">Wiltshire</option>
          <option value="Worcestershire">Worcestershire</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
       <label>Year/Group (Tick all that apply):</label>
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Reception" id="mce-reception">
          <label for="mce-reception">Reception</label>
       </div>
       <li>
       <div>
          <input                 type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Year 1" id="mce-year1">
          <label for="mce-year1">Year 1</label>
       </div>
       </li>
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Year 2" id="mce-year2">
          <label for="mce-year2">Year 2</label>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Year 3" id="mce-year3">
          <label for="mce-year3">Year 3</label>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Year 4" id="mce-year4">
          <label for="mce-year4">Year 4</label>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Year 5" id="mce-year5">
          <label for="mce-year5">Year 5</label>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Year 6" id="mce-year6">
          <label for="mce-year6">Year 6</label>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add all your relevant code directly to the question.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @InSync sorry, added the form code for that section

Comment: `display: block; width: 100%;` for the checkboxes mess up the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="input-wraper">
  <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="year-group" value="Reception" id="mce-reception">
  <label for="mce-reception" style="display: inline-block">Reception</label>
</div>
```

```css
.input-wraper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin: 3px 4px 3px 3px;
}
.input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```css
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-indent: 2%;
}
```

Try to remove the width: 100% and turn you're input and label on display: inline-block